# Show wave form of an mp3 from URL

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, avaudioplayer

I have an mp3 in a url and I am playing it with AVAudio player.
I want to show its wave form and subsequent progress in that wave form with some color change. 
How to do this, is there any sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following libraries:

- [FDWaveformView](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/fdwaveformview)
- [WaveformView](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/waveformview)

Comment: I have checked both samples, Second one is good(WaveformView) But could you tell me how play an audio file from web (URL) in that. Now both are using local mp3 files.